# Assign values to serial variables

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops

I want to assign values to serial variables. Something like:

```py
data_1 = a
data_2 = 2*a
...
data_n = n*a
```

How to do that using a loop?

Comment: With the function `eval()`

Comment: There is seldom a need to have `variable_x`, usually stored in a collection, [what is the xy problem?](https://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: i.e - How do you hope to use all these variables after you've created them?

Comment: I suggest to use a `list`

Comment: Did you check the answer?

Answer (score 0):

I don't remember any use-case in which polluting the global namespace would be beneficial. In these cases it's better to go with a dictionary or a list(when you have continuous integer indexes):

```py
a = 10
d = {f'data_{i}': a * i for i in range(1, 10)}
print(d['data_2'])  # 20
```

But now, I don't think you even need to store them. You can generate them easily on the fly with a simple function.

I'm going to show a bit more verbose approach using a class which give your the dict syntax for getting objects:

```py
class Data:
    def __init__(self, a) -> None:
        self.a = a
    def __getitem__(self, item: str):
        _, n = item.split("_")
        return self.a * int(n)
    
d = Data(10)
print(d["data_2"])  # 20
```

Comment: There's also no need to use a dict here – a list will be better since we are talking _sequential_.

Comment: @AKX Yes right. It was just a demonstration. Indeed we don't need any kind of containers. It's a simple calculation.

Answer (score -2):

```py
for i in range(1,n+1):
     eval("data_"+str(i)+" = "+str(a*i))
     exec("print(data_"+str(i))")
```

Comment: Thanks. However, an error 'SyntaxError: invalid syntax' popped up using the code.